# How do I make my purchased music be synchronized on Rhythmbox and in ~./ubuntuone/Purchased from Ubuntu One?

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one

I am signed up for the Ubuntu One service, and have my computer added.

Under System → Preferences → Ubuntu One, I have enabled all synchronizations, including for music.

System → Prefereneces → Ubuntu One, it shows this message:  "Synchronization Complete".

But, when (via Rhythmbox) I purchase a song, no synchronization occurs.  I can see the purchased song on the Ubuntu One web page, but the "Purchased Music" folder in Rhythmbox is empty, and the folder `~/.ubuntuone/Purchased` from Ubuntu One is also empty.  (So, the only way I can get at the song is to manually download it from the Ubuntu One web site to my computer.)

I thought that these synchronizations should just happen automatically, but it appears that is not the case for me, and I can't figure out why.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably bug [lp:684408](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/684408), which has been fixed in trunk. A workaround is to do something like

```
touch "$HOME/.ubuntuone/Purchased from Ubuntu One/xyzzy"
```

in a terminal; this should get everything syncing down again, and you can then remove that file.