# Music bought from ubuntu one music store stuck on "Transferring to your Ubuntu One storage"

Tags: 10.04, storage, ubuntu-one

I bought music from the Ubuntu One music store, and the status of the downloads are stuck at "Transferring to your Ubuntu One storage" under the "My Downloads" section of Ubuntu One Music Store. I can see the music bought from the web interface, but I'm unable to synchronize it onto my machine.

I've tried **[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16983/how-do-i-make-my-purchased-music-be-synchronized-on-rhythmbox-and-in-ubuntuone)** without success.

Has this problem been reproduced at all other than by me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [make certain your syncdaemon is connected and working correctly](https://askubuntu.com/q/16592/711). If the state of syncdaemon is stuck in something like `STANDOFF`, I'd recommend you restart it; this can be done in several ways, although I prefer doing it via entering the following in a terminal:

```
u1sdtool --quit
u1sdtool --start
sleep 30
u1sdtool --connect
```

If you find that it is OK, but it is busy, please use `magicicada` or `u1sdtool --waiting-content` to see if your music isn't queued up for download.

If it is connected and idle, and have tried [the solution for the only known remaining client-side issue that could cause this](https://askubuntu.com/q/16983/711) and it hasn't helped, please [contact support](https://one.ubuntu.com/support/).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this problem. There is no synchronization after the music were purchased to my u1 storage.
Just after clicking the restart button in the u1 preferences/devices it starts to sync.